# Does NX need to be installed globally by people who only want to run the app / e2e tests?

Tags: angular, reactjs, nrwl-nx

I created a workspace for **React** using **@nrwl/nx**. Now, if anyone clones my repo, do they also need to have nx installed globally?

And if not, how can they run stuff, say the e2e tests? When nx would be installed globally, they would do `nx e2e myapp-e2e`. I tried to run stuff in powershell instead (where I **do not** have nx installed globally) of the subsystem linux cli (where I **do** have nx installed globally). I got the error that the command nx could not be found. I tried to run with npx (`npx nx e2e myapp-e2e`) but with no luck.

Any thought on how to make this work for people who want to use my repo simply to run the app and the tests (and who are otherwise not interested in running nx globally)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need global `nx` installation, provided you point your mono-repo to a local copy of `nx` found at `node_modules/@nrwl/cli/bin/nx.js`.

**Here is an example:**

```json
  "scripts": {
    "nx": "node ./node_modules/@nrwl/cli/bin/nx.js",
    "start": "yarn nx serve",
    "build": "yarn nx build",
    "test": "yarn nx test",
    "lint": "yarn nx lint",
    "...": "..."
  }
```

Usage: `yarn nx e2e myapp-e2e`.

This way your mono-repo will be self contained. Works locally, in your CI/CI pipeline or any other node env.